# I'd like to delete this question but I can't

Tags: support

Can you delete [Assign an action to a simple button](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/263083)? I posted code I shouldn't have.

Comment: We wouldn’t delete it, it has well-received answers. If you can edit it with new code that represents the problem, please do so then we can redact the old revisions so they’re no longer visible

Comment: since you already received an answer, so should not be deleted :)

Comment: @Clive can you redact old revisions now? I've edited the question.

Comment: Sure @Kartagis. I've redacted the 10 previous revisions, the action is just awaiting approval by another mod and then they'll be permanently removed from the site

Comment: Thank you @Clive :)

Comment: Don't edit the question, until revisions aren't removed, or redacting doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a look at https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/id-like-to-delete-this-question-but-i-cant?noredirect=1#comment5727_3709 @kiamlaluno

Comment: Still, don't edit the question, or we cannot redact revisions.